# How to rename corrupted file extensions in bulk?

Tags: macos, terminal

For work I have a report auto-generated every week (written by an engineer, not me) that pulls in various documents. All of them are .docx, but in any given report roughly half return as ".docx[RANDOM CHARACTERS]," causing them to be unable to open until I manually fix the file extension for each one. I have seen how to bulk rename files (e.g. ".txt to .docx" across the board), but is there a way to use Terminal to categorically change the extensions for all files in a folder?

Tried this code:

`for file in *.docx*; do mv "$file" "$file%.docx}.docx"; done`

This added ".docx" to the end of every filename but did not remove all the random characters.

Ideally it would replace the ".docx[RANDOM CHARACTERS]" with ".docx" while leaving the other ".docx" files alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so, so close.  Your `${file%.docx}` expression is missing a `*` at the end of the `.docx` pattern.  The `*` will match (and then remove) any additional characters that follow the `.docx` string.  This is what it should be:

```
  for file in *.docx* ; do mv "$file" "${file%.docx*}.docx" ; done
```

You could make the command slightly more efficient by only selecting files whose name contains at least one character after the `.docx` string, like so:

```
  for file in *.docx?* ; do mv "$file" "${file%.docx*}.docx" ; done
```

Without that `?` the command will match and then rename existing `.docx` files to have the same name that they already have.  That's harmless, but inefficient.

Obviously if there's a danger that a rename will clobber an existing file (e.g. you have files named `abc.docx` and `abc.docx2`) or that two renames will collide (e.g. you have files named `xyz.docx1` and `xyz.docx2`) then you'll have to do something slightly more elaborate.  Using `mv -nv` instead of a plain `mv` would be an easy way to protect against those collisions.